# How to have key,key value pair and only keys in python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary,

```
  P_dic = {'ID': 'STD1'}
```

and I have output corresponding to this in a list.
      Lst = ['Len','Lin','lon']

So basically for an ID, there are three values associated to it.

I want to have something like,

```
 Result = {'ID': 'STD1'}: {'Len','Lin','lon'}}
```

I am unsure of how to save this inside python dictionary. Please help.

Comment: Are you looking for `{'ID': {'STD1': ['Len', 'Lin', 'lon']}}`? Your current output is illegal because your key must be a hashable type, and a `dict` is not.

Comment: Yes this output would do. Can you please help me with the code

Comment: Your data structure is kinda strange, sincerely consider something like this `{'ID': 'STD1', 'lst': ['Len', 'Lin', 'lon']}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you:

```
P_dict['lst'] = Lst # from Lst variable
```

or

```
P_dict['lst'] = ['Len','Lin','lon']  # direct assignment
```